# Retrieve excel cell text that is not wide enough

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I want to read excel display value, not value that excel internally saves. Problem is that when this value is wider that the cell it makes cell to display `#######` which is OK in excel. But I want to read this value from excel API. When I access property range. Text I also get value `########`. Is there a way to get value which will be displayed when cell is wide enough?
i.e some third property, not `Value2` nor `Text`.

My colleague said that there are three values in excel, one internal value how excel represents cell value, one what is currently displayed and one what will be displayed when there is enough space, is he right?

If this is not possible, I have another solution which might work. I used `AutoFit()` method to make cell wide enough and that I read value. But the problem is that I don't want to change width of columns. Is there a way to remember width, then change width so I can read cell, and that return it again to previous width?

Or maybe I should somehow apply formatting option to value of cell to get what will be displayed?

How to solve this?

Comment: What is the file version you are accessing (XLS and/or XLSX) ?

Comment: Currently XLSX, but in future should be both. So it should be some solution which is possible for both file types.

Comment: for XLSX there are free options out there... for XLS the only "good options" I know of are commercial... is a commercial library an option ?

Comment: Well, maybe you haven't understood my question. I don't need library for this, I'm using Microsoft office interop and excel api within it. I just ask for way to do this in excel interop api - programmatically

Comment: Thanks for the clarification... (I always prefer a library based solution since that doesn't need Excel installed and it works in server-scenarios like IIS/Windows Service too...) IF you need an Interop based solution then I wish you luck and hope that someone can provide you with that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VBA I would do this by getting the Value and the number Format, and then useing the VBA Format Function to format it, but I am not sure how to do this using c#.

As a matter of curiosity, why would you want to get the formatted value anyway?

Comment: Well, I synchronize my values with server, and I do that only for values that are changed. I have my inner structure where I keep values and when some object have new value I check it if it differs with my inner and than do sync. But problem is that for some numeric types excel cannot remember same precision as value at server and my inner value. So I remember this display value and sync only those objects where new display value differs with old one. I'll try to create value depending on number Format and Value.

Comment: All Excel numbers are stored internally and retrieved using .Value2 are double-precision floating point (this includes integers, currency, doubles, dates, times etc). I suggest you use the same internally and compare with a very small tolerance rather than messing around with .Text

Comment: Yep, you're right it's easier to do all this without formatting. Thanks Charles.